# How can I organize interaction between two divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `div` on page. One of them is hidden, and another one is visible. Both of them is on the same place, and form layers. The first is on background (we don't see it), and the second is overlay (we can see it).

I want to have button to be able to switch visibility of `div`. When I press the button it must change visibility of `div` (fist does to the background, the second goes to overlay).

How can I do it with `jQuery`?

*UPD*

Here is my try http://jsfiddle.net/0qth6jdn

The problem is I don't know how to make layers with `div`.

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net??

Comment: Oh, I don't have an account there. Need to registrate.

Comment: You don't have to... Just create the code and click save... Then, copy the URL here

Comment: I added example into jsfiddle.

Comment: Check my updated answer where I've changed your own fiddle.

Comment: You forgot to set the library on your fiddle. But check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to change the visibility, Jquery's `.toggle()` may be the easiest way to go.

[**Jquery Toggle Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

If you set both div's classes to be the same, even easier. Just call `toggle` on the button's click event:

```
$(".myClass").toggle();
```

Here's a simple example:
[**JsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sqnfayxt/)

**EDIT**

Here is your own fiddle updated. Instead of `visibility: hidden`, I've changed your style to `display: none;`, as it allows you to use Jquery's `.toggle()` without having to check for any condition:

[**Your JsFiddle Updated!!**](http://jsfiddle.net/0qth6jdn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Do this when your button is clicked (you have to change IdOfDiv1 and IdOfDiv2 to your actual div ids):

```
$("#IdOfDiv1").toggle();
$("#IdOfDiv2").toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

1. You create a `<input type="checkbox">` ABOVE THE `<div>` you want.
2. You give it a nice `id` like 'div-toggler`.
3. You set this css:

```css
#div-toggler ~ #your-hidden-div {display:none;}
#div-toggler:checked ~ #your-hidden-div {display:block;}
```

4. You create a new `<label for="div-toggler">` inside the other `<div>`
5. Style it the way you wish, to look like a button.
6. If you care about old browsers, that don't support `:checked` on css, use `[checked]` instead.
   The you create a `<label onclick="var e=document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('for'));e.setAttribute('checked',e.checked);" for="div-toggler">` if it doesn't work after the css change.

## **UPDATE:**

After seeing the new update, it's clear:

```js
if ($('#first').visibility == 'hidden' && $('#second').visibility == 'visible'){
```

should be

```js
if ($('#first').css('visibility') == 'hidden' && $('#second').css('visibility') == 'visible'){
```

## UPDATE 2:

Actually, this is the right code:

```js
window.replaceDiv=function() {
    if ($('#first').css('visibility') == 'hidden' && $('#second').css('visibility') == 'visible'){
        $('#first').css('visibility','visible');
        $('#second').css('visibility','hidden');
    }
}
```

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/gughtms7/

Answer (score 0):

There are a million ways to do this. If both `divs` have an id, you can simply toggle them, like so:

```
$('#id-of-your-button').on('click', function(){
  $('#id-first-div').toggle();
  $('#id-second-div').toggle();
});
```

Another way would be to toggle a class on a parent element:

```
$('#id-of-your-button').on('click', function(){
  $('#parent').toggleClass('switch');
});
```

And than apply all changes via css

```
#parent #id-second-div {
  display: none;
}
#parent.switch #id-first-div {
  display: none;
}
#parent.switch #id-second-div {
  display: block;
}
```

It all depends on your situation